# BASH - Replacement of regex match within a file

Tags: regex, bash, perl, sed

Given the following files:

input_file:

```
My inputfile, contains multiple line 
and also special characters {}[]ä/
```

template_file:

```
Contains multiple lines,
also special characters {}[]ä/

##regex_match## <= must be replaced by input_file

Content goes on
abc
```

output_file:

```
Contains multiple lines,
also special characters {}[]ä/

My inputfile, contains multiple line 
and also special characters {}[]ä/

Content goes on
abc
```

I thought about sed but that would be very cumbersome because of escaping and newlines. Is there any other solution in BASH?

Comment: give an example of your expected input and output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed -n -e '/##regex_match##/{r input_file' -e 'b' -e '}; p' template_file
```

If the regex is matched, read and output the input file and branch (end processing of the line and don't print it). Otherwise print the line.

The use of `-e` delimits parts of the `sed` commands so that the `r` command which reads the input file knows where the name of the file ends. Otherwise it would greedily consume the following `sed` commands as if they were part of the file name.

The curly braces delimit a block in the program that's like an `if` statement.

I tested this on MacOS, but it should be pretty similar for GNU. MacOS `sed` is much pickier about `-e` (among other differences which don't come into play here).

Comment: Very neat! Thank you. Would you mind to explain the following part? {r input_file' -e 'b' -e '}; p'

Comment: I hadn't known you could spread pieces of a block across `-e`'s. Awesome. :)

Comment: @PaulHodges You often have to for non-GNU sed, and in this case to avoid confusion about what delimits the filename.

Comment: @royskatt: The paragraph following the command is a prose description that follows the steps you're asking about. I'll add a little more for some clarification.

Comment: Seems not to work with regexes: sed -r -n -e '/(?<={).+\.global(?=})/{r input_file' -e 'b' -e '}; p' template_file. The PCRE is valid for another template file, however, sed moans the regex is incorrect.

Comment: @royskatt: `sed` doesn't understand PCRE. It only works with BRE or ERE (with `-E`).

Answer (score 3):

[perl](/questions/tagged/perl) solution just for variety's sake.

```
perl -0777 -lpe'
    BEGIN {
        open $fh, "<", "input_file";
        $input = $fh->getline
    }
    s/##regex_match##/$input/
' < template_file > output_file
```

Comment: Despite being Perl, that looks much less cryptic and more understandable than the sed solution. Thank you.

Comment: Though, it gives me an "Can't locate object method "getline" via package "IO::Handle" at -e line 1."

Comment: Works for me. You could [open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) if you want to dig for the bug.

Answer (score 1):

A *very* slight variation on the technique [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson) already posted, merely for discussion purposes -

```
sed '/##regex_match##/ {
       r input_file
       d
     }' template_file
Contains multiple lines,
also special characters {}[]ä/

My inputfile, contains multiple line
and also special characters {}[]ä/

Content goes on
abc
```

c.f. [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands).

He used `-e` options to pass commands, where I separated them with newlines. Usually a semicolon is enough, but apparently `r` makes other commands on the same line get ignored.

The `d` prevents the tag pattern from being printed.

Comment: `r` thinks everything is part of the file name until a newline or `-e` is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

With any awk in any shell on every UNIX box and with any characters:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{rec=rec sep $0; sep=ORS; next} /##regex_match##/{$0=rec} 1' input_file template_file
Contains multiple lines,
also special characters {}[]ä/

My inputfile, contains multiple line
and also special characters {}[]ä/

Content goes on
abc
```